# Overclocking, sensibly for a novice

Tags: 14.04, amd-processor, overclocking

MotherBoard is an ECS C51GM-M Processor is an AMD Athlon 64 X2 3800+

ive read many articles and have zero experience compiling software installs on ubuntu

(a learning link would be a lovely message)

but heres what i want to know i know bios is at most almost not involved in linux o.s.

i am wondering if theres a reliable program or app that will allow me to overclock my cpu

oh and before im asked yes i have 4gigs of ddr2 ram and a cpu cooling fan that takes up most of the case

any answers are greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Overclocking is usually done from the bios. The bios can be accessed by pressing a certain key when starting the computer. It does not matter what OS is running, eg the settings will apply to both Linux and windows.

Although, that chip is getting a little old now TBH :P

Comment: chip was given to me as a step up from a older single core, most people dont have money to buy high end computers i apologize ill try to work on that in the future